# How i delete old Kafka logs Safely in server.properties

Tags: apache-kafka

I used Kafka Version 2.3, I want to delete old kafka logs

there are two folders

1. `log.dirs=/var/www/html/zookeeper_1/zookeeper_data_1`
2. `kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2/logs`

What is the difference between two folders, and I want to delete old log?

Comment: Why are you putting kafka logs in /var/www when kafka is not a web server?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that the safest way to delete older logs is to properly configure your retention policy.

---

In Kafka, there are two types of log retention; *size* and *time* retention. The former is triggered by `log.retention.bytes` while the latter by `log.retention.hours`.

Assuming that you want a `delete` cleanup policy, you'd need to configure the following parameters to

```
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleanup.policy=delete
```

Then you need to think about the configuration of `log.retention.bytes`, `log.segment.bytes` and `log.retention.check.interval.ms`. To do so, you have to take into consideration the following factors:

- `log.retention.bytes` is a minimum guarantee for a **single partition of a topic**, meaning that if you set `log.retention.bytes` to 512MB, it means you will always have 512MB of data (per partition) in your disk.
- Again, if you set `log.retention.bytes` to 512MB  and `log.retention.check.interval.ms` to 5 minutes (which is the default value) at any given time, you will have *at least* 512MB of data + the size of data produced within the 5 minute window, before the retention policy is triggered.
- A topic log on disk, is made up of segments. The segment size is dependent to `log.segment.bytes` parameter. For `log.retention.bytes=1GB` and `log.segment.bytes=512MB`, you will always have up to 3 segments on the disk (2 segments which reach the retention and the 3rd one will be the active segment where data is currently written to).

Finally, you should do the math and compute the maximum size that might be reserved by Kafka logs at any given time on your disk and tune the aforementioned parameters accordingly. I would also advice to set a time retention policy as well and configure `log.retention.hours` accordingly. If after 2 days you don't need your data anymore, then set `log.retention.hours=48`.

Comment: I edit in  server.properties  with:- 
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleanup.policy=delete
log.retention.hours=1
log.retention.bytes=536870912
log.segment.bytes=536870912
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

But no change in logs in path /var/www/html/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2/logs 
Folder logs size continues to increase.
i want to delete old logs .

Answer (score 0):

One is Zookeeper data, the other is Kafka 0.8.2.2 data, which is not directly compatible with Kafka 2.3

You'd delete segments from the latter, however it'll have the potential to corrupt the topic if you do so, so you should let Kafka clean itself up